# Extract string between specific string variable

Tags: java, string, substring

I need to extract a string between two specific string variables. For example consider the string `x1-676y1-44z188x2-623y2-67z274`.  Now I need to detect `x1` and `y1` in the string, get all data in between `x1` and `y1` and store it as string not as character. Similarly get data between `y1` and `z1` and for other variables.

Below is my code that I tried:

```
bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
String str = new String(buffer, "UTF-8"); // prints character
Log.d("Data Transmitted", str);

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(str);
int a=sb.indexOf("x1");
char x1=sb.charAt(a+1);
System.out.println(x1);

int b=sb.indexOf("y1");
char y1=sb.charAt(b+1);
System.out.println(y1);
```

Comment: And what did you tried?

Comment: Yes. Write __code__.

Comment: String have nice method : int indexOf(String str)

Comment: You're on a good start. I would have used regex, but this should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   s.substring(s.indexOf("A"), s.indexOf("B"))
```

Comment: Ya it worked.But now it is taking x1 in output.I want only string between x1 and y1.

Comment: Did you think at +1 ?

Comment: Yes Now I am getting desired Output.Thank You.I did it as s.substring(s.indexOf("A")+1, s.indexOf("B"))

Comment: Javadoc is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring` method:

```
int x1pos = str.indexOf("x1");
int y1pos = str.indexOf("y1");
if (x1pos >= 0 && x1pos <= str.length() - 2 && y1pos >= 0 && y1pos > x1pos) {
    String between = str.substring(x1pos+2,y1pos);
}
else {
    //do something else
}
```